# D3 line chart Invalid value for <path> attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So i have the following js to create my `linechart`:

```
            var data = scope.dataset;
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.time.scale()
            .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.label);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.value);
            });

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.label = d.label;
            d.value = d.value;
        });

        var svg = d3.select("#lbLineChart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.label;
        }));
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        }));

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Price ($)");

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
```

Where the data is an array of objects:  `{label: 'mylabel', value: 5}`

```
Invalid value for <path> attribute
```

Im not quite sure what im doing wrong? ive checked the variables again and again but was unable to find where there is an error.

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: your x-scale is defined to manage time values, but the `label` property of your data consists of strings.